# Web table scraping: how do I find the column number of a cell in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an excel file with many Chinese names in the first row like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGR9S.png)

And what I am doing is to scrape some more Chinese names from a web table and the names are all at the 2nd col in each row (tr). I want to see if the names being scraped is already in my excel file. So I use a boolean have to keep track. It should return True if found. And I want to know the exact position (column number) of the found name, so I use name_position to keep track.

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('hehe.xlsx')
ws1=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Taocan')

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
web = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': "tc_table"})
trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    ls = []
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        ls.append(td.text)
    ls = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in ls]

    try:
        name = ls[1]

        have = False
        name_position = 1
        for cell in ws1[1]:
            if name == cell:
                have = True
                break
            else:
                name_position += 1


    except IndexError:
        print("there is an index error")
```

However, my code doesn't seem to work, and I think the problem is from the comparison of the names:

```
if name == cell
```

I changed to:

```
if name == cell.value
```

it still doesn't work.

***Can anyone help me with this? thanks/:***

Just to add on: the web page Im scraping is also in Chinese. So when I

```
print(ls)
```

it gives a list like this

```
    ['1', '\xe4\xb8\x80\xe8\x88\xac\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\x9f\xa5', '\xe8\xba\xab\xe9\xab\x98\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xbd\x93\xe9\x87\x8d\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xbd\x93\xe9\x87\x8d\xe6\x8c\x87\xe6\x95\xb0\xe3\x80\x81\xe8\x85\xb0\xe5\x9b\xb4\xe3\x80\x81\xe8\x88\x92\xe5\xbc\xa0\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe3\x80\x81\xe6\x94\xb6\xe7\xbc\xa9\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe3\x80\x81\xe8\xa1\x80\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe6\x8c\x87\xe6\x95\xb0', '\xe9\x80\x9a\xe8\xbf\x87\xe4\xbb\xaa\xe5\x99\xa8\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe9\x87\x8f\xe4\xba\xba\xe4\xbd\x93\xe8\xba\xab\xe9\xab\x98\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xbd\x93\xe9\x87\x8d\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xbd\x93\xe8\x84\x82\xe8\x82\xaa\xe7\x8e\x87\xe5\x8f\x8a\xe8\xa1\x80\xe5\x8e\x8b\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\xa7\x91\xe5\xad\xa6\xe5\x88\xa4\xe6\x96\xad\xe4\xbd\x93\xe9\x87\x8d\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\xa0\x87\xe5\x87\x86\xe3\x80\x81\xe8\xa1\x80\xe5\x8e\x8b\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe6\xad\xa3\xe5\xb8\xb8\xe3\x80\x81\xe4\xbd\x93\xe8\x84\x82\xe8\x82\xaa\xe6\x98\xaf\xe5\x90\xa6\xe8\xb6\x85\xe6\xa0\x87\xe3\x80\x82']
```

but if I

```
print(ls[1])
```

it gives Chinese name like "广州"

Comment: try changing `if name == cell` to `if cell.find(name) > -1`.

Comment: I tried just now and it says invalid syntax :C

Comment: It would work if `cell` and `name` are `string`.

Comment: So is there a way to convert them into string in this case? Or is there any way to compare without changing them to string

Comment: `cell = str(cell)` same way for `name` too.

Comment: I seems it still doesn't work. Because when I print(have), it gives False - but there are definitely some names in the excel file that are the same as some names from the web table

Comment: Anyway got it ! Thanks !

Comment: For parsing `csv` or `excel`, pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be more suitable than BeautifulSoup!